# Perform some actions on KeyboardInterrupt before celery worker exits

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celerybeat

Is there a way to perform some operations before exiting the celery worker when a keyboard-interrupt (say SIGINT) is encountered? I have tried using signals module in my tasks like so:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, keyboard_interrupt_handler)
```

But it doesn't work the way I expect it to. The `keyboard_interrupt_handler` does get executed but since it takes a few seconds to execute, the process is terminated before it can finish executing.

I have also tried to temporarily block the `SIGINT` signal with `signal.pthread_sigmask` and running the handler in a thread (since they can't be killed?) as well but it faces the same problem.

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try to implement a handler for the [worker-shutdown signal](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html#worker-shutdown). In general, [Celery signals](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/signals.html) are extremely useful and Celery users should get familiar with them, Celery events too.

Sample code:

```
app = Celery('my_tasks', include['my_tasks.tasks', 'their_tasks.tasks'])

@worker_shutdown.connect
def handle_worker_shutdown(**kwargs):
    mymodule.handle_worker_shutdown(app, _LOGGER, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks good and seemed to work as well when i added the handler inside the file where my tasks reside. But once I moved it to a separate file, it stopped executing. Any idea why? Do I have to register my signal handler somewhere?

Comment: I've added sample code in the answer - assuming you implemented the handler in mymodule.handle_worker_shutdown() it should work wherever you created your Celery instance... This is just a sample, copy/paste will not work - you need to write your own code...

Comment: I see. What I understand from this is that calling the handler is necessary somehow, for instance i can write this piece of code in the file i'm creating my celery app in? which, in fact, i did and it worked. Writing the handler standalone in a file won't work, right? Also, passing the app argument is necessary or I can just pass the `**kwargs`?

Comment: Worker will call any function that is annotated (decorated in Python parlance) with `@worker_shutdown.connect` - I do not get that "standalone handler"...

Comment: By that what I mean is that I created a file named `celery_signals.py` in one of my django apps and put the signal handler in it. But it didn't get executed on shutdown. When I put the handler in my `tasks.py` file, it did.

Comment: That is precisely what "mymodule" is in the sample. Rename "mymodule" to "celery_signals" and there you go! I am not familiar with Django, so I can't help with that. I use Celery without any web stuff to distribute millions of tasks per day...

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. And that's what I was saying that according to my understanding from this, my handler inside `celery_signals.py` even though decorated with `@worker_shutdown.connect` won't work, unless called like you suggested in your answer. I'm just curious about why that is.

Comment: Let's stop it here as the discussion is becoming a chat... If you want to chat come to the Celery IRC channel (https://webchat.freenode.net/ channel: #celery)